# Regexp to find all subnet blocks in config file

Tags: regex

i have such config file:

```
#DHCP Server Configuration file.

deny unknown-clients;

subnet 10.8.140.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 {
    host example{
            optian:param; 
    }
    host example2{
            option2:param2;
    }
}

subnet 20.8.110.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 {

}
```

And i need to find all **subnet** blocks.
The problem is subnet block can contain host blocks (with curly brackets). And i cant construct regexp to match those.

So the result should be:
1. subnet 10.8.140.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 { ... host {...} host{...}} 
2. subnet 20.8.110.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 { ... }

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: you're on a wrong way with RegExp's. It's not the best idea to use it to parse recursive structures

Comment: @Bhargav Modi, i have tried a lot. I think there is no sense to write them here.

Comment: @Vovan What language/tool are you using? Most of the regex flavors can't do what you want...

Comment: Personally I would just parse the file one line at the time. Regex really is not suited for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't named your programming language. Here comes an example using a [*recursive pattern*](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.recursive.php) in PHP (PCRE):

```php
<?php

$conf = file_get_contents('/path/to/dhcp.conf');

# We use a recursive pattern, check the link I posted above
$pattern = '/(subnet.*?)?\{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*\}/';    

preg_match_all($pattern, $conf, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo $match . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

PHP uses *Perl compatible regexes*, you can use the same pattern in Perl or other languages which use the same engine and support recursion.

Btw, the syntax higlighter seems to have fun with the pattern, but it is **not** a syntax error.

[Online example](http://3v4l.org/Fe7od)

Answer (score 1):

[Regex can't be used to match nested pattern of arbitrarily deep nesting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

But in you case, if the subnet blocks follow the *skeleton* **subnet|host|option** the deepness is finite.

By brute-force here what I got:

```
((|\s|\n)*subnet(|\s|\n)*((\d{1,3}.){3}(\d{1,3}))(|\s|\n)*netmask(|\s|\n)*((\d{1,3}.){3}(\d{1,3}))(|\s|\n)*\{(|\s|\n)+((|\s|\n)+host(|\s|\n)*(\w+)(|\s|\n)*\{(|\s|\n)*(\w*)\:(\w*)\;(|\s|\n)*\}(|\s|\n)*)*\})
```

Ugly AF. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/zL2eD3/3).

I use `(|\s|\n)*` too often, I actually allow no space between *subnet* and first ip : `subnet10.4.4.2` which is bad.

But you may allow no space between host-name and opening bracket, like in your code: `host example{`.